# How to initialise a char array with command line argument in C

Tags: c

I have just started learning C and I have a basic question. How do I read out a command line argument. For example, if I execute:

```
       ./main "test"
```

How can I get the command line parameter "test" into a variable:

```
         int main(int argc, char **argv){
             char s[] is supposed to equal "test"
         }
```

EDIT: Basically I want to create a new char array that equals argv[1].

Comment: Enter `strdup()` (POSIX). Or `char arr[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];` and `strcpy(arr, argv[1])`...

Answer (score 0):

```
char * s = argv[1];//to read the test
if(strcmp(s,"test") == 0){
    //the command line argument is equal to the string test
 }
```

Comment: your program crashes if there is no argument given

Comment: i have not written the complete program..i am only explaining how to achieve the task.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Irrelevant. OP is looking for the case where there **is** an argument. There's no need for this sort of nitpick. And while we are at it: you state that "argv[0] is the name of the program (main), argv[1] is the first parameter" - that's not universally true, it's implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments `argc` and `argv` of the main function are used to access the string arguments passed to your program when it is started. `argc` is the number of arguments passed. For example when run like this - `./myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3`, `argc` will have a value of 4. This is because along with the strings the user passes in the name of the program is also passed. That is `argv[0]` points to a string `myprogram`, `argv[1]` points to `arg1` etc. To get the nth argument then you must access `argv[n + 1]`.
Knowing this, to make a copy of the first argument you can do as follows

```
char * s = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
strcpy(s, argv[1]);
```

However I would advise making sure that the argument you want doesn't point to NULL before copying it. This is where argc is handy. Before accessing `argv[1]` I would check if `argc >= 2`.

There is a much better explanation here http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html or here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Edit:
Remember to free any memory you allocate via `free`
eg. `free(s)`.